# webdriver click event is slow with firefox

Tags: firefox, onclick, watir-webdriver, performance

I'm using `ruby 1.8.7` and `watir-webdriver 0.6.1`, and found that following script is very slow when click some link element under `windows 2003/2008 server`, but the same script is fast under `win7` and `windows2008 R2`:

```
log "try table menuitem, sub_menu_area=#{@sub_menu_area.inspect}"
link=@sub_menu_area.link(:text => name, :class => "SGLeftPanelText")  
log link.inspect  
link.fire_event("onclick")   
log "menu link clicked."
```

and the log shows:

```
I, [2012-12-22T01:02:46.944250 #5672]  INFO -- : Info: sub_menu_area=#"td", :id=>"tables_cell"}>

I, [2012-12-22T01:02:46.944250 #5672]  INFO -- : Info: try table menuitem, sub_menu_area=#"td", :id=>"tables_cell"}>

I, [2012-12-22T01:02:46.944250 #5672]  INFO -- : Info: #"SGLeftPanelText", :tag_name=>"a", :text=>"Support Cases"}>

I, [2012-12-22T01:03:03.100500 #5672]  INFO -- : Info: menu link clicked.
```

From the log, the click event takes `16 secs`, but on another machine with `win7`, it only takes `2 secs`, can anybody give me some suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the `click` method instead of `fire_event`?

Try replacing:

```
link.fire_event ("onclick")
```

with:

```
link.click
```

Comment: It is the same when use click method.